Movie/TV Show Ep with bloody screwdriver punching through car bonnet/hood
Have asked this on another forum but to no avail...
So I’m not entirely sure if this was even a movie (vs some sort of TV show) as my best googling efforts have been unable to track it down and I’ve searched on and off for maybe 15+ years.
My recollection of this movie is based on 2 key scenes and the fact that I was always pretty sure the main character in it was played by Edward Woodward, though I am starting to wonder if the reason I’ve been unable to track this down is because it wasn’t him and was some other British actor.
I am fairly sure it was either a mid to late 70s or early 80s production, set in UK somewhere, set around that time period.
Was some sort of supernatural/telekenesis/evil unseen force horror genre.
First memorable scene: A mechanic is working on a car in his workshop (I think he is under the car somehow working on the engine?) and some unseen ‘power’ causes the engine to start up killing the mechanic and in the process sending whatever tool he was using through the bonnet/hood of the car (yellow?) along with a jet of blood and the bloody tool (screwdriver?) then lands on the bonnet…
Second memorable scene: Main character (Mr Woodward) is driving along some UK country road and his car ends up going off the road (due to some psychic/telekinetic/evil force? – cant remember!) and he and the car ends up crashed upside down in a tree. From memory he is injured and trapped and can’t get his seatbelt off…

It was Edward Woodward. You're looking for the slow-paced horror film The Appointment  from 1981.

A schoolgirl takes a shortcut through some woods and is seized by an unseen malevolent force. She is never seen again and the authorities erect an iron fence around the woods to prevent a recurrence. Three years later, another schoolgirl regularly visits the fence and speaks with something that is invisible. The malevolent force seems to affect her family, first in dreams and later in more concrete ways.

Both scenes are there: A mechanic under a car killed by a bloody screwdriver shooting out of the hood (and landing on another), and Edward's character driving off the road and being trapped upside down in a tree, struggling to unbuckle his seatbelt (which he dreamt about). Here are the last 15 minutes:




Jsus Ttty F*#king Chr*st that is it Walt thankyou!!! I can't understand how I couldn't find that when I went through Edward Woodward wikipedia and IMDB pages previously. I mean I went through everything including his old TV shows after going thru the films. I can only think that maybe some of the info on 'The Appointment' was added in the last year or so. Regardless thanks for solving this mystery for me!
